# mysql "jammed" into every install although I don't want it

Tags: 16.04, apt, mysql

[Ubuntu 16.04]

I don't have `mysql` running on my machine, not do i want it.

I do need to install `redis-server`. so I did this:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install redis-server
    E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

so I went ahead and...

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1055 (4.4.0-1055.64) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-1055-aws (4.4.0-1055.64) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-1055-aws /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1055-aws
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-1055-aws /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1055-aws
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1055-aws
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-1055-aws /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1055-aws
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-1055-aws /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1055-aws
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-1055-aws /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1055-aws
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1055-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1055-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1054-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1054-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1052-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1052-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1049-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1049-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1048-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1048-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1047-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1047-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1044-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1044-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1043-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1043-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1041-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1041-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1039-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1039-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1038-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1038-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1035-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1035-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1022-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1022-aws
done
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-1055-aws (4.4.0-1055.64) ...
Setting up linux-image-aws (4.4.0.1055.57) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

and it just stopped at this point. had to CTRL-C out of it...

I tried again...

```
$ sudo apt-get install redis-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1022 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1035 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1038 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1039 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1041 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1043
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1044 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1047 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1048 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1049 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1052 linux-headers-4.4.0-1022-aws
  linux-headers-4.4.0-1035-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1038-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1039-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1041-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1043-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1044-aws
  linux-headers-4.4.0-1047-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1048-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1049-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1052-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1022-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1035-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1038-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1039-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1041-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1043-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1044-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1047-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1048-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1049-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1052-aws newrelic-daemon newrelic-php5-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  redis-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 113 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 343 kB of archives.
After this operation, 918 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 redis-server amd64 2:3.0.6-1 [343 kB]
Fetched 343 kB in 0s (1,595 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package redis-server.
(Reading database ... 357711 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../redis-server_2%3a3.0.6-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking redis-server (2:3.0.6-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

from that moment on it freezes and never finishes. and it just stopped at this point. had to CTRL-C out of it...

How do I untangle this mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `sudo apt-get install redis-server`, `apt-get` is telling you that

```
[snip]
2 not fully installed or removed.
[snip]
```

that means there are package in a "broken" state, neither installed nor removed.

`mysql-server-5.7` is one of those, that's why it keeps "popping up".

If you insist on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> out of it, these errors won't go away.

The easiest thing is to just get rid of it:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.7
```

In case `apt-get` complains, just let `dpkg --configure -a` do its thing (dont't press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, let it finish!) and then remove `mysql-server-5.7` with the above command.